# Problemas com utilização de requisição Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, sql, ajax

Quando tento fazer uma requisição para retornar uma consulta sql para os campos do formulário ele retorna apenas a primeira linha da tabela, como posso alterar meu código para que busque todas as linhas:

código que faz o select:

```
<?php
class Medico 
{
 public $nome;
}

try 
{
require "conexaoMysql.php";

$medico = "";
$especialidade = "";
if (isset($_POST["especialidade"]))
  $especialidade = $_POST["especialidade"];

$SQL = "
 SELECT Nome
 FROM funcionario
 WHERE Especialidade = '$especialidade';
";

if (! $result = $conn->query($SQL))
 throw new Exception('Ocorreu uma falha ao buscar os nomes: ' . $conn-
>error);

if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
   $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

$medico = new Medico();

$medico->nome = $row["Nome"];

} 

$jsonStr = json_encode($medico);
echo $jsonStr;

}
```

Código da função que faz a requisição

```
function buscaNome(especialidade)
{
 $("#nomeEsp").empty();  

$.ajax({

  url: 'php/buscaNomes.php',
  type: 'POST',
  async: true,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {'especialidade':especialidade},         

  success: function(result) {


    if (result != "")
    {                  
        var campoSelect = document.getElementById("nomeEsp");
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = result.nome;
        option.value = result.nome;
        campoSelect.add(option);

    }
  },

  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert(status + error + xhr.responseText);
  }

});  

}
```

Obs: Os resultados são colocados em um campo select html

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro a função [fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) retorna apenas uma linha do resultset por vez. Então para que todas as linhas retornadas do banco sejam acessadas é necessario usar um laço while para iterar sobre todas as linhas retornadas pelo banco. Isso pode ser feito assim:

```
//array de medicos
$medicos = [];

if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $medico = new Medico();
        $medico->nome = $row["Nome"];
        $medicos[] = $medico;
    }
} 

$jsonStr = json_encode($medicos);
echo $jsonStr;
```

Como pode ser visto no codigo, faz-se necessario retornar um array de médicos (em vez de apenas um objeto da classe medico). Pois a cada iteração no laço while é criado um novo objeto medico.

A mudaça na forma do retorna causa uma alteração no javascript. Agora é necessario adicionar um laço de repetição para acessar os indices do vetor `result`. Ajustando fica:

```
if (result != "")
{                  
    for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
        var campoSelect = document.getElementById("nomeEsp");
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = result[i].nome;
        option.value = result[i].nome;
        campoSelect.add(option);
    }

}
```

## Serializar variaveis privadas com json_encode

Se a sua classe `Medico` tiver atributos privados eles não serão serializados com `json_encode` automaticamente. Para isso acontecer deve-se implementar a interface `JsonSerializable`, mais sobre ela no [php.net](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php). Ao fazer isso fica mais ou menos assim:

```
    <?php
class Medico implements JsonSerializable{
    private $nome;
    public function setNome($nome){
        $this->nome = $nome;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize(){
        return ['nome' => $this->nome]; 
    }
}

$medico1=new Medico();
$medico1->setNome('nome1');
$medico2=new Medico();
$medico2->setNome('nome2');

echo json_encode([$medico1, $medico2]);
```

Sendo que o mais importante não é como o parametro nome é enviado para a classe, mas sim a existencia da função `jsonSerialize()`. Ao fazer isso é impresso no console algo mais ou menos assim:

```
[{"nome":"nome1"},{"nome":"nome2"}]
```

Isso deve resolver o problema de undefined apresentado com as versões anteriores do codigo.

Comment: Com as alterações, não listou nenhum resultado no campo do formulário.

Comment: Aparece "undefined"

Comment: Editei a resposta para solucionar o problema de undefined. Basicamente o json_encode não estava serializando atributos privados da sua classe medico.

Comment: Realizei as alterações, porém continua aparecendo apenas "undefined".